# Disable same origin policy react native webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am making a react native application and inside i am using react-native-webview to render some webpages where i need to gain access to elements. Inside that webpage we have multiple iframes but since iframes don't have the same domain it gives me error as

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://XXXXXXXX.XX" from accessing a frame with origin "https://XXXXXXX.XX". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

how can i disable same-origin-policy in react-native-webview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the CORS protection, just add your domain to it using [originWhitelist](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#originwhitelist) prop